# Are there any differences between the sample covariance matrix and the population covariance matrix?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, variance, covariance-matrix

Are there any differences between them (w.r.t) the calculation. I know the sample covariance matrix uses the sample data and the population covariance matrix uses the random varibles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample covariance matrix is an estimation for the population covariance matrix. As all estimators, it uses sample data and is experimental. On the other hand, the population statistics is theoretical and can be calculated when you know the joint distribution.